# How to use a variable as operator?

Tags: php, variables, operators

how can I do this?

```
$v1=105;
$v2=90;
if ($value=='subtraction'){
    $operator='-';
}else{
    $operator='+';
}

$new_value=$v1.$operator.$v2;
```

So it should return 105-90=15 or 105+90=195. But how can I use the $operator variable as a operator? For example this doesn't work:

```
eval("$new_value=$v1".$operator."$v2");
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do the math in the conditional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest *not* doing this, but to use `eval`, you'd have to do it like this:

```
// You need to escape the $ in $new_value
eval("\$new_value = $v1 $operator $v2");
```

I suggest doing it something like this instead (ie: Don't use a variable for operator, just do the calculation):

```
$v1=105;
$v2=90;
if ($value=='subtraction'){
    $new_value= $v1 - $v2;
}else{
    $new_value= $v1 + $v2;
}
```

Comment: Well, eval is not a pre;-), what is better?

Comment: @Jordy: Just do the math in the `if` statement.  See my 2nd example.

Comment: Ok, but I need to do it for 20 times or so, so I make a function I think. Perhaps thats better? But thank you very much!;-)

Comment: @Jordy: That's a good idea, a function (or functions), would be another (and maybe better) option.  Anything to avoid using `eval` :-P

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is better, but if you really want to do something tricky, I think you can have a variable hold a function (instead of an operator).

```
//untested hypothetical example

$myOperation = function Add($num1, $num2){
  return $num1+$num2;
}
```

Haven't done that in PHP personally, but I think you *can*...

Answer (score 0):

*maybe you can change this:*

```
<?php
$v1 = 105;
$v2 = 90;
if($value=='subtraction')
    $v2 *= -1;
$new_value = $v1 + $v2;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make $operator a function?

```
$v1 = 10;
$v2 = 20;

$substraction = function($a, $b) {
    return $a - $b;
};

[...]

$someString = 'substraction';
echo $$someString($v1,$v2);
```